# Visual output of Matplotlib bar chart - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on getting some graphs generated for 4 columns, with the COLUMN_NM being the main index.

The issue I am facing is the column names are showing along the bottom.  This is problematic for 2 reasons, first being there could be dozens of these columns so the graph would look messy and could stretch too far to the right. Second being they are getting cut off (though I am sure that can be fixed)

I would prefer to have the column names listed vertically in the box where 'MAX_COL_LENGTH' current resides, and have the bars different colors per column instead.

Any ideas how I would adjust this or suggestions to make this better?

```
for col in ['DISTINCT_COUNT', 'MAX_COL_LENGTH', 'MIN_COL_LENGTH', 'NULL_COUNT']:
    grid[['COLUMN_NM', col]].set_index('COLUMN_NM').plot.bar(title=col)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Graph Example]

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can plot points one by one and setup the label name for each point:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, :])
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
label = ['l1','l2','l3','l4','l5']
for n,(p,l) in enumerate(zip(data,label)):
    ax.bar(n,p,label=l)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.legend()
```

This is the output for the code above:

[image]